# Set "from" or "reply-to" fields as user email(not verified)

Tags: sendgrid

It's not possible anymore to send an email "from" an unverified user.

The use case:

- user fills out the website form and specifies contact data(**user email address**)
- sends the form to server
- server uses Sendgrid service and sends an email to corporate email, depending on data it may be one of the four email addresses. The field "from" should be equal to the **user email address**

It was working Up to May 2023. For now, as I can see, the only way to set "from" field is to verify it via Domain Authentication or Single Sender Verification.

1 Were there any changes that affected the sending process and remove the possibility to specify user's email in the "from" field?

2 If it is anti-spam protection, Is it possible to specify several authenticated recipients(in my case managers' emails) to be able to send them emails without "from" restrictions?

Thanks

{"errors":[{"message":"The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements","field":"from","help":null}]}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reply_to` option to set the email of the user. Keep the `from_email` as your verified email.